# GPU doesn't render the image with many moving particles

Tags: rendering, gpu

I recently was making a scene with particles being moved from forcefields and after making the particles over 100k[image]

But while rendering as always the first frame didn't show the particles at all but in second frame where the particles should've appeared GPU simply doesn't render, but CPU does it but in a detail lossy way. I tried on my PC (GTX1070) and at friends PC (RTX2070 super) both had absolute same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it struggles so much is the motion blur. since it has to know where the particle was to make the blur effect. and with so many particles looks like GPU just cant keep up. simply turning off the Motion blur helped, but if you need motion blur, you probably need to use CPU Only render. Why CPU only? because if you use GPU render with CPU acceleration the tile that supposed to be rendered with GPU won't let the CPU finish the job.
I hope it will help someone :)